# Mongoose in Docker container can't connect to mongodb instance running on host VPS

Tags: node.js, docker, express, mongoose, deployment

I have been trying to get a CircleCI pipeline going that deploys an admin panel for one of my projects. One of the jobs in this pipeline is to publish a docker image containing a node.js/express.js API to which and from which a front-end will send and receive data. This image is then pulled and run by the VPS upon successful publish.

The problem that I currently experience is that this express.js application within the docker container can't seem to connect to the MongoDB server on the host VPS. The container is successfully started by docker. However, internally, it errors and shuts down with the below log output:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:792:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:767:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:540:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      '<HOST_IP>:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: '<HOST_IP>:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 84443078,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out
            at connectionFailureError (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:372:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:28)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
            at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:589:8)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'ResetPool', 'InterruptInUseConnections' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Based on this and based off of what was read online, I immediately had the following hunches:

- Docker port mappings must be invalid or missing
- The configured binding within the node.js/express.js app must be faulty
- The `bindIp` value within the `/env/mongod.conf` file must be faulty

#### So I tried and verified the following

I believe my `docker run` command contains correct mappings (sorry for the env variables, the ports are at the start):

```
docker run -it -d -p ${ADMIN_BE_PORT}:${ADMIN_BE_PORT} -p ${MONGO_PORT}:${MONGO_PORT} -e BLADE=${BLADE_IP} -e MONGO_PORT=${MONGO_PORT} -e MONGO_USER=${MONGO_USER} -e MONGO_PW=${MONGO_PW} -e PORT=${ADMIN_BE_PORT} -e PORT=${ADMIN_BE_PORT} -e ADMIN_APP_HOST_PROD=${ADMIN_APP_HOST_PROD} -e ADMIN_APP_HOST=${ADMIN_APP_HOST} -e GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID} -e GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID} ${DOCKER_HUB_USER}/<reponame>:<tag>
```

I had a seemingly identical problem with the docker container containing the frontend. Before setting Vite's `--host` flag to true to bind the server to all interfaces, `wget`ing the frontend returned `connection refused`, so I tried to search for similar resolutions in the context of express.js. I therefore tried adding a `host` variable containing the value `0.0.0.0` and assigning it as a parameter to the following, to no avail:

```
const host = '0.0.0.0';
...
app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Fushaa backend listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Then I tried adding the same `0.0.0.0` ip to the `bindIp` value inside the `mongod.conf` file. I have made the value look like so: `127.0.0.1,<VPS_IP>,0.0.0.0`. And like so: `127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0`. And also like so: `0.0.0.0`. Very silly, but gotta try.

#### So what now?

I have also tried a couple of other silly things, but I don't think these are worth mentioning. To end with an actual question: *What am I missing, and what can I try next to make sure that my node.js application can connect to the mongodb server on the host machine?*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure your firewall carefully. `ufw status` showed that my firewall was blocking all but my own development machine on the port the `mongod` service uses.